# is there a way to make screen sharing fit to the whole screen?

Tags: macos, mac

I am currently using screen sharing (mac osx), but I find it hard to use because it is not in full screen mode, i.e. -- I can see the local computer windows, bar, etc. and that's distracting.

Is there a way to make the screen look as if I am actually sitting in front of the remote computer? Nothing from the local computer? (then, there would be some key combination you press to exit this mode.)

I couldn't find anything to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In Lion and Mountain Lion, the screen sharing client supports full screen mode; just press the full-screen button in the top right corner of the screen sharing window (see [KB #PH4530](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4530)). Note that if your computer's screen isn't the same resolution as the one you're sharing, it won't be quite like sitting in front of the computer.

Getting out of full-screen sharing is a little tricky, since key combinations just get passed to the other computer. Instead, mouse up to the very top of the screen, and the local computer's menu bar will drop down, with an added "get out of full-screen mode" button on the far right.